# How to fix Error pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: column " " does not exist LINE 1: ...oad(filename, detail, folder, dateupload)

Tags: php, postgresql

How to fix my error code program, I want to insert/upload a file on database and folder local use database postgresql and php, but show error, how can I fix it?

This is my action_upload.php

```
 <?php

 require_once 'config.php';
 //Buat konfigurasi upload
 //Folder tujuan upload file
 $eror      = false;
 $folder        = './upload/';
 //type file yang bisa diupload
 $file_type = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','bmp','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','sql','txt','enc');
 //tukuran maximum file yang dapat diupload
 $max_size  = 1000000; // 1MB
 if(isset($_POST['btnUpload'])){
//Mulai memorises data
$file_name  = $_FILES['data_upload']['name'];
$file_size  = $_FILES['data_upload']['size'];
//cari extensi file dengan menggunakan fungsi explode
$explode    = explode('.',$file_name);
$extensi    = $explode[count($explode)-1];

//check apakah type file sudah sesuai
if(!in_array($extensi,$file_type)){
    $eror   = true;
    $pesan .= '- Type file yang anda upload tidak sesuai<br />';
}
if($file_size > $max_size){
    $eror   = true;
    $pesan .= '- Ukuran file melebihi batas maximum<br />';
}
//check ukuran file apakah sudah sesuai

if($eror == true){
    echo '<div id="eror">'.$pesan.'</div>';
}
else{
    //mulai memproses upload file
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data_upload']['tmp_name'], $folder.$file_name)){
        //catat nama file ke database
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO file_upload(filename, detail, folder, dateupload) values ("'.$file_name.'", "'.$_POST['keterangan'].'", 
                              "'.$folder.'", "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'")';
        $result= pg_query($sql);
        echo '<div id="msg">Berhasil mengupload file '.$file_name.'</div>';
    } else{
        echo "Proses upload eror";
    }
}
}
?>
```

This is my message error:

```
 Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: column "Copy of Pengajuan_Judul_Skripsi_Dospem_Pak_Indra(1).xls.enc" does not exist LINE 1: ...oad(filename, detail, folder, dateupload) values ("Copy of P... ^ in D:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\testingupload\action_upload.php on line 40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are running in to is that you are enclosing your strings in double-quotes: `values ("'.$file_name.'"...`.  In Postgres, enclosing a name in double-quotes will be interpreted as a case-sensitive column name.  Therefore, you should be enclosing in single-quotes.

However, the format you are using is a bit insecure, as it lends itself to SQL injection attacks.  You are better off using `pg_query_params()`:

```
$d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO file_upload(filename, detail, folder, dateupload) values ($1,$2,$3,4)';
$result = pg_query_params($sql,array($filename,$_POST['keterangan'],$folder,$d));
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)